# JQuery syntax error found in firebug but not in my code

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, post

In a PHP page I have a drop-down list that triggers the jQuery change function and does a POST with AJAX in order to populate a second drop-down list in the page.

It should all be pretty simple, however Firebug throws an syntax error for a '?' that appears in my code at run-time which isn't actually in my code.

This is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#taglist').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../includes/ajax.php",
            data: "taglist=" + $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value'),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#catlist").html(response.catlist);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#catlist").html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });​
    });
});
```

Following, is the PHP code that executes in ajax.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['taglist'])){
    $catlist = '<select name="cat_id[]" size="5" multiple id="cat_id[]">';
    $catlist .= fillselecteditmultiple(0, 0, $_POST['taglist']);
    $catlist .= '</select>';

    echo json_encode(array("status"=>"success", "catlist" => $catlist));
}
```

fillselecteditmultiple() outputs the options for the populated  highlighting those that should be pre-selected. It works fine as I use in other pages without a problem. To make sure it wasn't an error being thrown from the function itself, I even tried changing the function to output a simple $catlist='abc' string as a response, still the same error.

The strange part is that Firebug throws an error at the last 2 lines of the javascript code like you can see in the image attached:

[image: Firebug error]
[image: Source code on execution]

What could be causing cause the '?' to appear in my code?

Comment: What editor are you using (dreamweaver, aptana, notepad++, etc) try copy and paste the entire code into a new file and see if it helps. I've had issues with dreamweaver putting funny things in my code in the past, Aptana saved me from this (and many other issues)

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this code but when i copy paste it in notepad++ its show });? to me after end of the ajax call declaration and that is the only error in that code.

Comment: That's sooo strange. I've been working on this for 2 hours and that ? isn't there! I'm using Dreamweaver. 
@StasGrin: You're right, there *was* a problem with my encoding, but how did you figure that??

Comment: @bikey77 he he, just a lot of practice, and intuition.

Comment: But how was that the 1st thing that struck you? I'm simply curious! :)

Comment: When a program doesn't know how to represent a unicode code point, it prints a question mark inside a square (I suppose you have seen this before), or in case it cannot, a simple question mark. An unexpected question mark always makes a developer suspect of encoding.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll keep it well in mind!

Comment: @StasGrin: Please put your comment in an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer, thanks.

Comment: heh, @Áxel answers better :) p.s. ok, i posted it.

Comment: @StasGrin mine is not a truly answer, but an advice to our questioner. If you think the advice is oseful you can include it in your answer. But the "correct answer" point is for you. Best regards.

Comment: by the way, a must-read about this issue:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check your encoding. When you see "strange" symbols in the end of a line, that can be caused mostly with encoding troubles.

And in addition, common advice:

> When a program doesn't know how to represent a unicode code point, it
>   prints a question mark inside a square (I suppose you have seen this
>   before), or in case it cannot, a simple question mark. An unexpected
>   question mark always makes a developer suspect of encoding.
>  (c)
>   Áxel

Comment: Many thanks, it has been a good conversation over this matter.

Answer (score 1):

you send in javascript code this data,

```
data: "tag=" + $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value')
```

but in php file you try to get $_POST['taglist'],

variable names are not the same.

try to change data: "taglist=...." or  $_POST['tag'].

Comment: Correct, in my actual code both variables are the same, but from various testing and debugging efforts I pasted the wrong code here. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll change it in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Debug the code step by step. First put a `else` statement in your `ajax.php` file and check where the execution goes. If it goes in `if` statement then put a `die()` function on each line to check where error come. One possible error in your code is that you are sending `tag` in your ajax function and you are getting `$_POST['taglist']`. `#taglist` trigger this ajax function, its value is not posted. Only the value that you give in `data` attribute is posted. So change your if condition from

From

```
if(isset($_POST['taglist'])){
```

To

```
if(isset($_POST['tag'])){
```

This may be the reason. Else is good.

Comment: Correct, in my actual code both variables are the same, but from various testing and debugging efforts I pasted the wrong code here. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll change it in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a space over there .. Remove the space after   });​

Comment: Space has nothing to do with this problem

Comment: Sometimes the space has been pasted as a special character